# decoding json data in php using ajax

Tags: php, json, ajax

I'm trying to decode json file via php  posting with ajax

```
$.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'http://147.175.98.165/zadanie6/index.php/meniny/3',
                data:'{"stat":"Cesko","datum":"all","dni":"meniny"}',
                success:function(msg){
                    $("#vypis").html(msg);
                }});
```

If i try this code to decode JSON file

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));

$data=$_GET;
var_dump($data);
var_dump(json_decode($data));
var_dump(json_decode($data, true));
```

I will get the following result

```
array(1) { ["{"stat":"Slovensko","datum":"all","dni":"meniny"}"]=> string(0) "" } NULL NULL
```

I dont know if I have a bad access to data decoding or I am bad at posting data. Is there any way  to get to the value of this $_GET["stat"] or something like this ?

Comment: Learn the difference between a text literal, and an object literal. Right now you are sending a single string value as `data`, and that is presumably not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `data` wrong. Pass it as object:

```
url:'http://147.175.98.165/zadanie6/index.php/meniny/3',
data: {"stat":"Cesko","datum":"all","dni":"meniny"},
```

And in PHP side use just `$_GET['param']`:

```
var_dump($_GET['stat']); // 'Cesko'
```

---

If you need all data in one key, then

```
data: {dataInfo: {"stat":"Cesko","datum":"all","dni":"meniny"}},
```

And in php `$_GET['dataInfo']`